# ERROR: null value in column "interaction_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql

Help.  Please.

Error occurs with table, sequence, and either of the commands shown below.  It's the old story, it worked, I cleared the DB to get ready for a demo, and ....

```
CREATE SEQUENCE interaction_seq;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Interact (
     webRequest text NOT NULL,
     interaction_id integer DEFAULT nextval('interaction_seq'),
     cTime timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() ,
     uid integer default NULL,
     successful boolean default(false)
);
insert into interact values ('::COOKIE::::',DEFAULT);
insert into interact values ('::COOKIE::::');
```

Seems to me the first, at least, should work.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: should have included this:ALTER TABLE ONLY Interact ADD CONSTRAINT interaction_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (interaction_id);

Comment: Always mention the columns in a query, also the INSERT query.